# Select:hover doesn't work

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

I have a css drop menu that opens on mouse over, within the menu I've also a select-box. The problem is whenever i click on select box the menu disappears.

what i've tried is to add `#year-select select:hover,`

css that opens menu

```
#menu li:hover .dropdown_1column, 
#menu li:hover .dropdown_2columns, 
#menu li:hover .dropdown_3columns,
#menu li:hover .dropdown_4columns,
#year-select select:hover,
#menu li:hover .dropdown_5columns {
    left:-1px;
    top:auto;
}
```

html

```
<select name="year-select" ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
        <option value="2012">
...
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B9eUM/

Comment: Can you post a working example (jsfiddle)?

Comment: here you go http://jsfiddle.net/B9eUM/

Comment: It works fine for me on Firefox 22. What browser are you using?

Comment: it works fine for me too. when you click the form it will submit and make the page reload so the menu disappears.

Comment: @rabotalius It works for me on Chrome as well

Comment: very strange, on firefox works for me too. maybe it depends on os?

Comment: Hey guys just try hovering ur mouse over the select box for a while then u will see what is wrong .

Comment: Hey ur problem is that whenever the mouse after clicking on select moves out of the drop down the select part does not closes .

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the mouse after clicking on select moves out of the drop down the select part does not closes . 

Well you can just create a small drop down box just like ur menu one instead of using select tags.